# How to extend line across entire violin plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Dataframe as example:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame("b" = runif(1000, min = 2, max = 10),
                 "c" = runif(1000, min = 2, max = 10),
                 "d" = runif(1000, min = 2, max = 10))

df_2 <- data.frame(id = c("b", "c", "d"),
                   cutoff = c(5, 3, 5),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df <-
  pivot_longer(
    df,
    cols = c("b", "c", "d"),
    names_to = "id",
    values_to = "value"
  ) %>%
  left_join(df_2, by = "id")
```

I can now make a violin plot (or a boxplot, same issue) with a line overlaid:

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = id)) +
  geom_violin(aes(y = value)) +
  geom_line(aes(x = id, y = cutoff, group = 1), color = red)
```

[image]

What I'd like though is three lines (don't need to be connected) each of which extend across the entire width of a single violin, at the cutoff value specified in `df_2`.

I can do this manually with `geom_segment`, but is there a better, more programmatic way?

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = id)) +
  geom_violin(aes(y = value)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 0.55, xend = 1.45, y = 5, yend = 5), color = "blue") +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 1.55, xend = 2.45, y = 3, yend = 3), color = "blue") +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 2.55, xend = 3.45, y = 5, yend = 5), color = "blue")
```

[image]

I understand that at some fundamental level the x-axis is ordered by factor level, with `b` = 1, `c` = 2 etc., so asking for a line intersecting x = 0.9 would require specifying corresponding y value.  In another sense though, `ggplot2` clearly knows (in some sense) that the region above x = 0.9 (that is, y values intersected by a vertical line at x = 0.9) is associated with factor level `b` because the corresponding violin for `b` overlaps that region.  Is there a way to get at that information?

Comment: I would do this by adding a geom_errorbar layer to plot df2 and set the ymax and ymin both to the same y-value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `geom_errorbar()`.  So change your second block to:

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = id)) +
  geom_violin(aes(y = value)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(x = id, ymin = cutoff,ymax = cutoff), color = "red")
```